# How do I get cells to store the value back into the source object?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm currently tinkering around with TableView to figure out a good way to handle it. Right now I'm using the PropertyValueFactory to populate the table and the TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn() as CellFactory.

My problem: I can edit the cells, but the changes don't get stored anywhere. Even just sorting the table reverts the value back. How do I get it to put the value back into the e.g. SimpleStringProperty in the model class? Bonus points if it avoids ridiculous amounts of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work, as long as your model object exposes the properties properly. I.e. you should have a model class structured as

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName ;
    }

    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
    public final String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }
    public final void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName ;
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

and then you can just do

```
TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
// In Java 8, I prefer:
// firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().firstNameProperty());
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```